# silverlight 4 treeview slow on expanding when many items

Tags: silverlight, performance

In XAML I have:

```
<sdk:TreeView x:Name="navigationTreeView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
    <sdk:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="sdk:TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </sdk:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" />-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Title}"/>                        
            </StackPanel>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</sdk:TreeView>
```

In code behind:

```
this.navigationTreeView.ItemsSource = nodes;
navigationTreeView.ExpandAll();
```

There are 1000 items as children of one node. If I'm not expanding elements everything is fine. But when I expand that node it's pretty slow (10 sec maybe). What could I do to speed it up?

Silverlight 4, 2010 april toolkit.

Comment: You should check out the answer from [this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837953/virtualizing-treeview-in-silverlight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike WPF, Silverlight (until Silverlight 4, not sure about 5) does NOT support UI virtualization for hierarchical data, and this is why when you expand the node, the 1000 items which are inside the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` are not virtualized and take more than 10 seconds to load.

I believe Telerik's `RadTreeView` has its built-in UI virtualization, but the control is not free.

The best solution I have found so far is from [this site](http://learnwpf.com/post/2011/01/13/Virtualizing-TreeView-for-Silverlight-with-Diagrams.aspx). Please note it is still a `ListBox` solution, however, because it doesn't use `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, it is fully virtualized and looks exactly like a `TreeView`. Also by looking at the source code, it is quite easy to implement.

[image]

I know it is not the perfect answer for this question but at least give you some alternatives. :)

Comment: I wish speed and efficiency would have always been top priority of silverlight's team. Would have been a better technology.

Comment: Thanks @ren, yes, I felt a bit dissapointed when I found out WPF had no issue with it...

Answer (score 2):

This is how the TreeView works.  It's virtualized by default: it won't create TreeViewItems until they're needed.  However, you're expanding the entire tree which forces all items to be created.  That's just inherently slow.  If you really need this sort of behavior (where all choices are expanded), I'd suggest something else like a ListBox.  Anything that is scrolled off the screen won't be created until it's needed (but see [this caveat](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/200402.aspx/1).)

Answer (score 1):

My bad stack panel is not in the right place...

Ok try this instead:

```
<sdk:TreeView x:Name="navigationTreeView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
            <sdk:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="sdk:TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </sdk:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" />-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>

            <sdk:TreeView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>                
            </sdk:TreeView.ItemsPanel>
        </sdk:TreeView>
```

Adding:

```
        <sdk:TreeView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>                
        </sdk:TreeView.ItemsPanel>
```

Let me know the results :D

Comment: nope again. I'm starting thinking there is nothing could be done here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" />-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Title}"/>                          
        </VirtualizingStackPanel>
    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Replace the normal StackPanel with one VirtualizingStackPanel...